# How do I embed a .wav file in a php if statment?

Tags: php, html

I am a noob to php and coding in general so pardon my ignorance.
I am trying to play a wav file from a php if statement. When I echo html for the sound I get this error.

PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected '" type="' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting ',' or ';' in /var/www/html/colums.php on line 67

line 67 being

```
        echo "<audio autoplay><source src="sounds/beep.wav" type="audio/wav" 
        autoplay></audio>";
```

Here is my code:

```
    <?php
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sound=1");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['sound'];
    }
    $sound=$row['sound'];
    if ($sound = "1"){
            echo "<audio autoplay><source src="/sounds/beep.wav" 
    type="audio/wav" autoplay></audio>";

    }
    ?>
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the problem within you code lies inside of the quotes. in lots of languages(php included) you can't embed quotes inside of quotes. to reslove your problem you need to add a backslash before every quote inside the quotes that make up the echo. example: echo "";

Comment: also you do need to fix what nickzor said above and you need to do the same for the while statement because you are using a conditional statement.

Comment: the while is fine

Comment: I am not sure why the while would work fine, but if it works for you, that's fine. Did my quote suggestion help?

Comment: If you do not know, then I would suggest you check it out. You could start with the sample code in the php manual: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php

Comment: You are very much wrong about this.

Comment: Thanks so much. That was the problem. All working now.

Answer (score 0):

The problem from what I can see at a quick glance is in your if statement.

```
 if ($sound = "1"){
```

In php a single "=" is assignment of value. "==" and "===" is for comparing the value. So, right now you are assigning the value of 1 to $sound technically. To fix the problem you should just need to replace it with double equals.

```
if ($sound == "1"){
```

Also refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/80646/how-do-the-php-equality-double-equals-and-identity-triple-equals-comp)  for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the reply and helpful tip. The problem was more related to Nick's suggestion. But I needed to fix the == too. Thanks for the link.

Answer (score 0):

> Found several mistakes in your code ,

1. You cannot assign $row['sound'] out side the loop. either it should be $row[0]['sound'] or $sound variable should be inside the while loop.
2. if($sound = 1) will not return error , but logically it's incorrect , it should be ($sound == 1)
3. you cannot use " inside a string if the string is quoted by " , ( same for ' ). you need to add slashes like \" or \'

Suppose below code will works...

```
        <?php
    $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE sound=1");
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
    echo $row['sound'];
    $sound=$row['sound'];
    if ($sound == 1){
            echo "<audio autoplay><source src=\"/sounds/beep.wav\" type=\"audio/wav\" autoplay></audio>";
}}
    ?>
```